# Error trying to send items in list Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to send each item in the list individually but if this cant be done then sending each item on a new line works just as well

Heres the code

````py
playlists = []

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.content == '=links':
        for x in playlists():
            await message.channel.send(x)
    if message.channel.id == 772290124117442581:
        playlists.append(message.content)
        await message.channel.send(f'Added:')
        ```await message.channel.send(f'`' + message.content + '`')
````

Heres the error:

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call any parameters from a list. So basically, you can't use parentheses like `playlists()`. You just have to change `for x in playlists():` to `for x in playlists:`.

Comment: AHH ty i spent the whole day on this cuz im new to this

Comment: You could just use `message.channel.send("\n".join(playlist))`